# Query working in MySQL directly, but not in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am using MySQL query in PHP but it's not working in PHP. But when I run it in MySQL, it's working well.

In this query I am subtracting result of sum(EventData.odometerKM) with the result of another query.

While I am not using limit, it's returning "Subquery returns more than 1 row"
and I want all not in limit.

Here it's returning with limit 1:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [licensePlate] => 
    [1] => 15745455.854492635
    [sum(EventData.odometerKM) - (SELECT  sum(EventData.odometerKM) from Device LEFT JOIN EventData on Device.deviceID=EventData.deviceID where DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`timestamp`), '%d-%m-%Y') = '27-06-2017' AND Device.isActive=1 group by Device.licensePlat] => 15745455.854492635
)
```

Code:

```
$sqll = "SELECT  Device.licensePlate, sum(EventData.odometerKM) - (SELECT  sum(EventData.odometerKM) from Device LEFT JOIN EventData on Device.deviceID=EventData.deviceID where DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`timestamp`), '%d-%m-%Y') = '27-06-2017' AND Device.isActive=1 group by Device.licensePlate ) from Device LEFT JOIN EventData on Device.deviceID=EventData.deviceID where DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`timestamp`), '%d-%m-%Y') = '28-06-2017' AND Device.isActive=1 group by Device.licensePlate ";

$result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sqll)or die("MySQL error: " . mysqli_error($conn) . "<hr>\nQuery: $query");;
$count=1;
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
     '.$rows['sum(EventData.odometerKM)'].'<br>';
    //$count++;
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($rows);

}
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: It's usually best to store dates and date/time values in their native `DATE` or `DATETIME` column types. Additionally it's generally best to avoid anything but the ISO-8601 date format `YYYY-MM-DD` when manipulating dates as formats like `MM-DD-YYYY` can be ambiguous, they might be `DD-MM-YYYY`. If you use the native data type you can `INDEX` these columns for better performance and use operators like `BETWEEN` in a meaningful manner. `MM-DD-YYYY` dates cannot be sorted without a lot of complicated string mangling.

Comment: you have syntax error in `while{}` loop. so try to do check first that anything coming or not like this:-`while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){print_r($rows);} `

Comment: why this `sum(EventData.odometerKM) - sum(EventData.odometerKM)`

Comment: @AlivetoDie  error:Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: @always-a-learner error:Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: that's an error? i don't think. You mean to say that now it is printing more than one time but you want only one time?

Comment: If it fails with that error, I don't see how it would work in the command line.

Comment: @AlivetoDie it's a warning but and query working as string returning this array Array
(
    [0] => 
    [licensePlate] => 
    [1] => 15745455.854492635
    [sum(EventData.odometerKM) - (SELECT  sum(EventData.odometerKM) from Device LEFT JOIN EventData on Device.deviceID=EventData.deviceID where DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`timestamp`), '%d-%m-%Y') = '27-06-2017' AND Device.isActive=1 group by Device.licensePlat] => 15745455.854492635
)

Comment: have you tried group by?